# Pandas: flatten a multi-level config into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yaml

I have a yml config file with following values:

```
content:
  test_group_1:
    segment_1:
        hero:
          '1.0': segment 1 hero msg for 1
          '1.1': segment 1 hero msg for 1.1
    segment_2:
        hero:
          '1.0': segment 2 hero msg for 1
          '1.1': segment 2 hero msg for 1.1
  test_group_2:
    segment_1:
      hero:
        '1.6':  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
    segment_2:
      hero:
        '1.6': segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

I want to match each value under `hero` to its corresponding message. So I need a dataframe like the following:

| target | hero | level1 | level2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | segment 1 hero msg for 1 | segment_1 | test_group_1 |
| 1.0 | segment 2 hero msg for 1 | segment_2 | test_group_1 |
| 1.1 | segment 1 hero msg for 1.1 | segment_1 | test_group_1 |
| 1.1 | segment 2 hero msg for 1.1 | segment_2 | test_group_1 |
| 1.6 | segment 1 hero msg for 1.6 | segment_2 | test_group_2 |
| 1.6 | segment 2 hero msg for 1.6 | segment_1 | test_group_2 |

The key here is that the config **needs to be dynamic to support multiple levels**

So something like the following needs also be supported:

```
content:
  test_group_1:
    segment_1:
      sub_segment1:
        hero:
          '1.0': sub-segment 1 hero msg for 1
          '1.1': sub-segment 1 hero msg for 1.1
        villain:
          '1.0': sub-segment 1 villain msg for 1
          '1.1': sub-segment 1 villain msg for 1.1
      sub_segment2:
        hero:
          '1.0': sub-segment 2 hero msg for 1
          '1.1': sub-segment 2 hero msg for 1.1
        villain:
          '1.0': sub-segment 2 villain msg for 1
```

In this scenario the dataframe should add:

- another `level` column
- another one for `villain` message (the lowest level is for values
  and the column names can be provided separately so I am not too
  bothered about the names)
- `villain` message doesnt have `1.1` for `sub_segment2` so this should either be `null` or not provided

I have been able to get the data in right format for strict configs but not for the ones that can have dynamic number of levels. Any help here will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the config file is a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'content': {'test_group_1': {'segment_1': {'hero': {'1.0': 'segment 1 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1',
                                                     '1.1': 'segment 1 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1.1'}},
                              'segment_2': {'hero': {'1.0': 'segment 2 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1',
                                                     '1.1': 'segment 2 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1.1'}}},
             'test_group_2': {'segment_1': {'hero': {'1.6': 'segment 1 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1.6'}},
                              'segment_2': {'hero': {'1.6': 'segment 2 hero '
                                                            'msg for 1.6'}}}}}
```

Then, assuming one wants to create a dataframe from the dictionary, can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) do the

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j,k,l): config[i][j][k][l] 
                            for i in config.keys()
                            for j in config[i].keys()
                            for k in config[i][j].keys()
                            for l in config[i][j][k].keys()},
                            orient='index')

[Out]:
                                                          1.0  ...                         1.6
content test_group_1 segment_1 hero  segment 1 hero msg for 1  ...                         NaN
                     segment_2 hero  segment 2 hero msg for 1  ...                         NaN
        test_group_2 segment_1 hero                       NaN  ...  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
                     segment_2 hero                       NaN  ...  segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

[image]

If one doesn't want the index columns as, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as follows

```
df = df.reset_index()

[Out]: 

   level_0  ...                         1.6
0  content  ...                         NaN
1  content  ...                         NaN
2  content  ...  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
3  content  ...  segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

[image]

If needed, one can also rename the first columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) as

```
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'type', 'level_1': 'group', 'level_2': 'segment', 'level_3': 'message_type'})

[Out]:

      type  ...                         1.6
0  content  ...                         NaN
1  content  ...                         NaN
2  content  ...  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
3  content  ...  segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

[image]

A one-liner that would do all that was shared above would look like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j,k,l): config[i][j][k][l]
                            for i in config.keys()
                            for j in config[i].keys()
                            for k in config[i][j].keys()
                            for l in config[i][j][k].keys()},
                            orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'type', 'level_1': 'group', 'level_2': 'segment', 'level_3': 'message_type'})


[Out]:

      type  ...                         1.6
0  content  ...                         NaN
1  content  ...                         NaN
2  content  ...  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
3  content  ...  segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

[image]

For this specific case, as the `message_type` is always `hero`, if one wants to use that as the column name for the `message` column, use the previous column names as values in the column `target`, and drop the column `message_type`, one can do the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j,k,l): config[i][j][k][l]
                            for i in config.keys()
                            for j in config[i].keys()
                            for k in config[i][j].keys()
                            for l in config[i][j][k].keys()},
                            orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'type', 'level_1': 'group', 'level_2': 'segment', 'level_3': 'message_type'}).set_index(['type', 'group', 'segment', 'message_type']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4': 'target', 0: 'hero'}).drop(columns=['message_type'])


[Out]:

      type         group    segment target                        hero
0  content  test_group_1  segment_1    1.0    segment 1 hero msg for 1
1  content  test_group_1  segment_1    1.1  segment 1 hero msg for 1.1
2  content  test_group_1  segment_2    1.0    segment 2 hero msg for 1
3  content  test_group_1  segment_2    1.1  segment 2 hero msg for 1.1
4  content  test_group_2  segment_1    1.6  segment 1 hero msg for 1.6
5  content  test_group_2  segment_2    1.6  segment 2 hero msg for 1.6
```

---

**Notes:**

- If one's dictionary has more levels, one would have to adjust the operation to consider the additional levels, but the logic would be the same.
- Depending on the desired output, one might have to do additional tweaks to the above operations.
- Usually it is not a good practice to share images of the dataframes, but in this case it allows one to have a better overview of how the dataframe looks like.